# I am looking for a Regex Validation to avoid " in the text field . I have tried using the below formula But its not working

Tags: administration, developer

REGEX(Company_History__c, '[\"]+')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this, just:

```
FIND('"', Company_History__c) > 0
```

REGEX works on the entire field, so you probably needed this instead:

```
REGEX(Company_History__c, '.*".*')
```

Comment: Thank you ..You saved my day  
Some modification it made the magic 
REGEX(Company_History__c, '.*["“].*')